# Better way to define UDT's in Cassandra database

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver, user-defined-types

We are trying to remove 2 columns in a table with 3 types and make them as UDT instead of having those 2 as columns. So we came up with below two options. I just wanted to understand if there are any difference in these two UDT in Cassandra database?

**First option is:**

```
CREATE TYPE test_type (
    cid int,
    type text,
    hid int
);
```

and then using like this in a table definition

```
test_types set<frozen<test_type>>,
```

vs

**Second option is:**

```
CREATE TYPE test_type (
    type text,
    hid int
);
```

and then using like this in a table definition

```
test_types map<int, frozen<test_type>
```

So I am just curious which one is a preferred option here for performance related or they both are same in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really depends on how will you use it - in the first solution you won't able to select element by `cid`, because to access the `set` element you'll need to specify the full UDT value, with all fields.

The better solution would be following, assuming that you have only one collection column:

```
CREATE TYPE test_type (
    type text,
    hid int
);

create table test (
  pk int, 
  cid int
  udt frozen<test_type>,
  primary key(pk, cid)
);
```

In this case:

- you can easily select individual element by specifying the full primary key. The ability to select individual elements from `map` is coming only in Cassandra 4.0. See the [CASSANDRA-7396](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-7396).  Until that you'll need to get full map back, even if you need one element, and this will limit you on the size of the map
- you can even select the range of the values, using the range query
- you can get all values by specifying only partition key (`pk` in this example)
- you can select multiple non-consecutive values by doing `select * from test where pk = ... and cid in (..., ..., ...);`

See the "Check use of collection types" section in the [data model checks best practices doc](https://docs.datastax.com/en/landing_page/doc/landing_page/dataModel.html).